# how to fix cordova navbar that falls down on IOS only?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm submitting cordova build to android and ios.. unfortunately on ios, navbar falls down in every menu.

[White space on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC7DN.png)

[Navbar pushed down and not sticking to top when scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGWwi.png)

I'm using node.js v8.11.2, cordova 8.0.0, 9.0 ios deployment target and i've tried in every iphone, navbar keeps falls down.

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000"/>
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent"/>
```

I also read some post about IOS status bar problem and tried to add some code above to config.xml and still not working as expected.

Comment: could you inspect whats causing the gap in the safari debugger?

Comment: Try adding `viewport-fit=cover` to your meta viewport in your HTML.

Comment: @IraW only happened in ios mobile app, not in browser.. can it be debugged?

Comment: @FaisalAmirullah yeah you go into your developer menu for safari and you can debug a phone if you've enabled USB debugging on that device

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t it because on top of iOS displays are system info data (time, Wi-Fi etc.). So app is basically pushed down, so best way for me was specify “StatusBarBackgroundColor” to correspond with your navbar.

Steve